# Display chunk options in output Quarto

Tags: r, echo, quarto

Is there a way to include the chunk options in the output?

For instance, in this case:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
editor: visual
---

```{r}
#| code-fold: true
#| label: example

1 + 1
```
````

How to get

```
#| code-fold: true
#| label: example
```

in the output (on top of them being actually used)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `echo: fenced` to your chunk options. It'll display all the chunk options in your output (except `echo: fenced`) as well as the ticks to make the chunk fully reproducible.

You can also add `echo: fenced` in your global options.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
editor: visual
---

```{r}
#| echo: fenced
#| code-fold: true
#| label: example

1 + 1
```
````

[image]

---

A second, less recommended option (more prone to errors) would be to add the options twice:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
editor: visual
---

```{r}
#| code-fold: true
#| label: example

#| code-fold: true
#| label: example

1 + 1
```
````

[image]